# Next Button on Java DB Program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, awt, resultset, javadb

I'm trying to create a simple app in Java. It is like a contact list with a few functions such as next, previous, first, and last buttons. I wrote some code for the "next" button. My program runs but when I click on the "next" button it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Employees.Workers.btnnextActionPerformed(Workers.java:199)
    at Employees.Workers.access$200(Workers.java:11)
    at Employees.Workers$3.actionPerformed(Workers.java:111)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
```

Below is my code:

```
public Workers() {
        initComponents();
        DoConnect();
    }

    public void DoConnect(){

        try{    
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";

    String uName = "Administrator";

    String uPass = "*********";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);

    stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );

    String SQL;
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM Administrator.Workers";

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    //identify the Columns
     // We want to go through all the records from our table. Thats why we used a while loop
    rs.next();
    int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
    String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
    String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
    String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
    String job_title = rs.getString("Job_Title");

    textID.setText(id);
    textFirstName.setText(first_name);
    textLastName.setText(last_name);
    textJobTitle.setText(job_title);



    }

    catch(SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());

    }


        }



 private void btnnextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
       try {
if ( rs.next( ) ) {


    int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
    String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
    String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
    String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
    String job_title = rs.getString("Job_Title");

    textID.setText(id);
    textFirstName.setText(first_name);
    textLastName.setText(last_name);
    textJobTitle.setText(job_title);



}
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied & pasted the code correctly? Something seems very off at the end... The "private void btnnextActionPerformed" is defined twice and doesn't end properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your doConnect method, you've decleared `rs` as a local variable...

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
```

Meaning that when you try and use in your buttons action handler, it is either `null` or not what you've previously loaded from your database

Try removing the deceleration

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
```

This assumes that `rs` is declared properly somewhere else, which it must be for the program to compile

Comment: Thanks! I removed ResultSet and it worked! I have already declared the ResultSet st in the beginning. I don't need to declare it again as a local variable.